# Python Lambda with an alternative return value (best practice?)

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

In some cases its handy to use Python lambda's to define callbacks inline.

```py
some_func(callback=lambda: foo())
```

However, in the case when the callback expects a return value, unrelated to the function, it becomes a bit awkward.

Let's say we want the function to return a constant.

```py
some_func(callback=lambda: (foo(), False)[1])
```

... another workaround:

```py
def tail(*args):
    return args[-1]

some_func(callback=lambda: tail(foo(), False))
```

Note, `False` is only used as an example, it could also be a variable in the namespace.

```
some_func(callback=lambda: (foo(), some_variable)[1])
```

While this works its rather ugly/awkward, is there some way to format the expression without making a temporary list/tuple?

Answer (score 2):

If you always want to return the last value, and if you don't want to create a temporary list or tuple, then use `and` and `or` operators, like this

```
some_func(callback=lambda: (foo() and False) or some_variable)
```

This will execute `foo` first and the return value will be `and`ed with `False`. Even if the `foo` returns something which is truthy, `and`ing with `False` makes sure that the result will be `False`.

Since the first part of the expression is `False`, `or` will evaluate and return the second operand. So, irrespective of the result of the result of `foo`, you will get the value you want.

Comment: This only works if you want to return a constant value of `False`, if you wanted to return a tuple or True... or a value when you dont know its truth state - it wont work.

Comment: While the code works, personally, I think it looks messier than simply using a tuple. Alternatively, simply don't use lambda and define your own function. It'll probably look neater too.